# Git - Rolling back to before changes

Tags: git

I have been editing and creating files on my local repo, when i issue the git status command i see the following.

```
# On branch master
# Changes not staged for commit:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
#   (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
#
#   modified:   app/database/migrations/2013_06_06_111226_update_users_table.php
#
# Untracked files:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
#
#   app/database/migrations/2013_06_12_092117_create_private_message_tables.php
no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
```

I have made a mistake in one of the files, now i want to start again.

How do i go back to before i made the changes and added to the files listed?

Comment: FYI: the status message tells you exactly what to do if you want to get rid of changes.  `(use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the untracked file, simply delete it if you don't want it anymore.  For advanced / large-scale cleanup, look at `git clean`.  For the modified file, simply do:

```
git checkout app/database/migrations/2013_06_06_111226_update_users_table.php
```

And it will go back to the clean copy from your last commit.

Comment: Thank you, thats exactly what im looking for